# Launcher-button show-desktop

Tags: launcher, show-desktop

With 18.04 we had a setting to add a show-desktop button on the launcher.

With 20.04 we did it ourselves by installing xdotool and creating a .desktop-file.
This does not work anymore; because of Wayland?

So, how to do it in 22.04?

Answer (score 0):

By accident, I found a solution that works fine for me:
hovering the mouse over the launcher, draw the mouse-wheel down.
But this is using another workspace, so ALT+TAB etc. are not working anymore.